# Personalize ActionBar/toolbar (change size and add image)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Im trying to implement a layout made in photoshop, that has the actionbar/toolbar with different height and a image on there but just the upper half inside the bar and the other half outside the bar.

As you can in the following image:

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c2LI.jpg)

Is this viable to do ? And how ? 
Can you give me some tips ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Toolbar from the support library to your layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then following the Android developer guides you can achieve that: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

You can also use the Android Studio new activity and will create mostly of the work of the toolbar for you.

PS: We will not create the layout for you!, please review the Help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic